# Dispose AlertBox Flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, hierarchy

I am using a `StreamBuilder`. In certain cases an `AlertBox` is displayed but when stream updates, `AlertBox` still remains there and on clicking any button it gives error: *method 'ancestorStateOfType' was called on null*. What should I do?

Comment: Did you try `Navigator.pop(context);` to hide the `AlertBox` ??

Comment: Where should I place it? I mean since it's ancestor has been destroyed due to stream update, if I just pop it out it says: *looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe*.

Comment: Can you provide some codes to be able to help?